# Prevent a process from starting and block its launching

Tags: android, process, permissions

My problem is the next :

When an user hold search's button on an android phone, and this, while a progress bar is in action,  the following error message is displayed:

```
 ERROR / AndroidRuntime ( 16794 ): java.lang. SecurityException: Requesting codes from com.google.android.voicesearch (with uid 10028) to be run in process com.xxxx.myApplication (with uid 10088)
```

Thus, further to this message I tried several things: kill the process ' com.google.android.voicesearch ' :

*JAVA code :*

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH)
{           
if (!event.isLongPress() && !Utils.getMyProgress().isShowing())
{
searchProducts();
}
else  
{   
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.google.android.voicesearch"));
}
return true;
}
```

Unsuccessfully! Thus the idea is to prevent the process 'com.google.android.voicesearch' from being started
every time the user of the telephone maintainings for a long time the key(touch) "to look for" of its telephone (example on htc, this key(touch) exists. Rather, a physical and not tactile key(touch)!)

Maybe is it possible to block the launch of this process ('com.google.android.voicesearch') in the in the manifest.xml, while my application is launched :

*manifest.xml :*

```
<application 
android:debuggable="false"
android:enabled="false"
android:killAfterRestore="false"
android:process="com.google.android.voicesearch">
</application>
```

Any idea ? 
Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement search with assistance from the Android system (to deliver search queries to an activity and provide search suggestions), your application must provide a search configuration in the form of an XML file called the [searchable configuration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html). It configures certain UI aspects of the search dialog or widget and defines how features such as suggestions and voice search behave. This file is traditionally named `searchable.xml` and must be saved in the `res/xml/` project directory.

According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/searchable-config.html), you only have to remove the voice entries from that file.